# Почему на нерусские фамилии не распространяются правила русского языка?

Tags: орфография, ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Речь, например, об армянских фамилиях, таких как Мкртчян. Фамилия не русская, у армян другая грамматика и другой алфавит. Не логичнее было бы переводить ее на русский, соблюдая правила "ча-ща"? Ведь в аналогичной ситуации в украинских фамилиях правила грамматики соблюдаются: Полищук, Корнейчук и т.д.
Это же касается не только армянских, но и других нерусских фамилий (сейчас, к сожалению, не приходят в голову конкретные примеры).
Какое правило тут работает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что написание фамилий вообще не подчиняется правилам русского языка, (их склонение происходит по правилам, а исходный вид таков, как записан в паспорте, при переводе на русский старались сохранить буквенный состав): лингвистика здесь уступает юриспруденции.Более того: если гражданка Чащина, например, захочет стать Чящыной (законы это позволяют), грамотное написание фамилии будет определяться исключительно паспортом.

Правило написания гласных и, а, у после согласных ж, ш, ч, щ не распространяется на иноязычные собственные имена (Жюль Верн, Шяуляй, Ащыозек) и некоторые нарицательные (брошюра, монтежю), а также сложносокращенные слова и аббревиатуры (в них допускаются любые буквосочетания)для сохранения традиции передачи фонетических законов исходной страны. В русском языке это называется традиционным написанием.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что окончание  "ян"  является показателем почти всех армянских фамилий; в армянском языке 99% фамилий оканчиваются на "ян" , поэтому в русском языке сохраняется написание языка источника. Изменение окончания в русском языке приведет к искажению самой фамилии.. Вы правы София, здесь, после ч  произносится звук а с призвуком й. В армянском, в отличии от русского , звук й сохраняется. Ср.: յան. Մկրտչ*յան*.

Answer (score 2):

ВСЕМ ИЗВЕСТНО ПРАВИЛО

После Ж, Ш, Ц буквы Ю и Я пишутся только в виде исключения, в том числе в иноязычных именах собственных, например: Цюрих, Свенцяны, Сен-Жюст.

[ГРАММА.РУ ПРЕДЛАГАЕТ ТАКОЕ ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ](http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=0&flag=1&RG2=all&page=73)

В некоторых словах заимствованного происхождения буквосочетания ЧЮ и ЧЯ передают дополнительную, особую по сравнению с обычной мягкость согласного:, т.е. служат особо сильными сигналами мягкости. Особенно часто такие буквосочетания встречаются в именах собственных.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Смягчение Ж, Ц  в иностранных именах  понятно: твердый звук можно смягчить при произношении, но как произнести Ч еще мягче? Можно предположить, что в фамилии Мкртчян после Ч произносится мягкий вариант звука А не с призвуком И, как обычно, а с призвуком Й, но это в качестве версии. Надо  консультироваться с носителями языка.